# FPDF: align cell with multicell

Tags: php, fpdf

I am trying to align a cell which contains image with a multicell which contains details related to the image such that both the image and details would display side by side. After searching the web, I found some method to do that. (I called the details out from database):

```
$pdf = new PDF();
$pdf->AliasNbPages();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Times','',12);
$image_height = 37;
$image_width = 37;


foreach($inventories as $key => $inventories) :

    $image = $inventories['image'];
    $resourceID = $inventories['resourceID'];
    $learningcentre = $inventories['learningcentre'];
    $title = $inventories['title'];
    $quantity = $inventories['quantity'];
    $description = $inventories['description'];

  $pdf->Cell( 40, 20, $pdf->Image($imagesDirectory.$image, $pdf->GetX(), $pdf->GetY(), $image_height, $image_width), 0, 0, 'L');
  $pdf->MultiCell(140,8,$resourceID."\n".$title."\n".$learningcentre."\n".$quantity."\n".$description, 1,1);
  $pdf->Ln();

 endforeach;
```

However, when the result reaches the end of the page, the image would get cut off and the details cell would be pushed to the next page as shown on the picture below

[image: output image]

I am new to FPDF and have been trying to search for a solution but to no avail. Any help would be appreciated.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm an FPDF noob myself but have you tried the AcceptPageBreak function?

Something like this (copied from fpdf website):

```
function AcceptPageBreak()
{
    // Method accepting or not automatic page break
    if($this->col<2)
    {
    // Go to next column
    $this->SetCol($this->col+1);
    // Set ordinate to top
    $this->SetY($this->y0);
    // Keep on page
    return false;
    }
    else
    {
    // Go back to first column
    $this->SetCol(0);
    // Page break
    return true;
    }
}
```

As a reference, the [fpdf tutorials](http://www.fpdf.org/en/tutorial/index.php) are really helpful.  I suspect [this one in particular](http://www.fpdf.org/en/tutorial/tuto4.htm) would help you for what you're doing.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I tried using the AcceptPageBreak function but it doesn't work. In the example given on fpdf tutorial, AcceptPageBreak function is used for documents with too many columns. Is there any way to use them for rows too?

Comment: I also tried using SetAutoPageBreak function. But the cell with image file seems to ignore that function

Comment: @Arastal Sorry for not getting back to you sooner.  Have you tried using the table function instead of multicell?  In reading the documentation, multicell seems to work best for free flowing content that doesn't necessarily have to line up with content in another column.  Have you tried using their [tabling feature?](http://www.fpdf.org/en/tutorial/tuto5.htm) It really seems as though that's really what you're trying to make (at least from my point of view).

Comment: Hi sorry, didn't notice to reply. I did try using the table function. But I guess I didn't really understand the code from the example as the result isn't satisfying when I tried using them. Can you explain to me how basic table works?